# BUG - No done button for select tag in IOS

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using the latest ionic and have a simple select tag.

```
<select class="assertive bold" ng-change="changeQuantity({cartItem: part})" ng-model="part.quantity" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:101"></select>
```

When I run the code with `ionic emulate ios`

[image]

Why is there no done button for the select? Shouldn't that be default? How do I fix this to display a done button?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Although this is a late answer, I'm sure more people will end up here while searching for a solution to this issue.

By default in your app.js in .run() the hideKeyboardAccessoryBar is set to true, so just find

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
```

and change it to

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
}
```

Comment: Still works for me in Ionic 3. I just wanted to note that this fix still works with Ionic updating from 2 to 3.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is doing:

```
if (Keyboard) {
  Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
  Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
}
```

The new plugin was exposed as global Keyboard, rather than cordova.plugins.Keyboard, and then the hideFormAccessoryBar is for form elements, rather than just for keyboard typing.

Answer (score 2):

I have fought this issue for over four hours. The recommended answer, hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false) failed repeatedly, with every possible combination of cordova.Keyboard, windows.Keyboard, $window.cordova.Keyboard, yes, inside deviceready, etc. etc. Resolved all conflicts between this and the older plugin.

No joy.

Solution: REMOVE THIS PLUGIN. Guess what. You get your Done button back. Run the following command:

`ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard`

Comment: Also confirming your solution, did you notice any side-effect because of removing this ionic keyboard plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Remove this plugin!

sudo cordova plugin remove ionic-plugin-keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me since I needed the accessory bar only in one instance, the accepted answer is old, and I am using cordova-plugin-keyboard instead. I used it with an onOpen handler.

```
if (window.Keyboard) {
  window.Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved when put this line on config.xml:

```xml
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
```